# How to Write a unit test with laravel queue mail?

Tags: laravel, email, testing, queue, tdd

I already finish the code to sending the mail by queue, and it`s working fine,
and I want to write a test for it (just want to test the mail that it should be send out normally without failing by queue, and to the right person), but how?

```
Mail::to($user->email)->queue(new Welcome($user));
```

Comment: Since you are already using Facades you can use `Mocking` of which documentation can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mocking).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Now I'm using the MailTracking to test the mail
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6e802e56af1f19d53464d667b3e6aa48

Answer (score 9):

You would do something like this (depending on your setup):

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\User;
use App\Mail\Welcome;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SendInvitationEmailTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    function mails_get_queued()
    {
        Mail::fake();
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();
         
        $this->post('/route/to/send/the/welcome/mail');

        // Mail::assertQueued(Welcome::class);
        Mail::assertQueued(Welcome::class, function ($mail) use ($user) {
            return $mail->user->id === $user->id;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Thank you! I don't need to use traits for something already existing.

Comment: What 2nd parameter in `Mail::assertQueued(Welcome::class, 1);` does? What does 1 for?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend grabbing the queued emails from `Mail::queued`. It's a simple array that then gives you all the power you want.

Like this:

```
$queuedEmails = Mail::queued(CustomerEmail::class);
$this->assertCount(1, $queuedEmails);
$email = $queuedEmails[0];
$this->assertEquals('status_complete', $email->handle);
```

You can run asserts as you're used to, which provide more meaningful messages in the case of failure. Unfortunately, `Mail::assertQueued`'s failure report isn't very specific or helpful:

```
The expected [App\Mail\MyEmail] mailable was not queued.
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

That's if you simply return true or false in the callback version. Note that you can use asserts in the callback, which is great, it's just more awkward if you need to check more than one email.

Comment: Thanks. Using Mail::assertQueued, I can't assert the recipient separately.

Comment: I would recommend making it clear that you're talking about assertQueued when you mention unclear failure, as I read this answer at least three times convinced you were talking about `Mail::queued` and being put off from it as a solution before I actually tried it.

Comment: Where did you find `Mail::queued` and how can I find what methods are available? It doesn't seem to be anywhere in the current docs.

Comment: Nvm, using `dd` I can now see that it allows you to access all the variables passed to the mailable's view. Very cool.